# Is it rational to suspend belief in everything except necessarily true/false statements?

Tags: belief

Is it rational to suspend belief, in **any** shape or form, in **every** statement unless it is logically necessary or incoherent?

For example, is it rational to simply not believe that the sun will rise tomorrow or even believe it probabilistically by refusing to attach a probability to it?

One may argue that this is not pragmatic since we perform many actions in life and many actions imply belief. But why would an action imply belief? What if it simply implies bets?

For example, I may leave the house for a walk not because I **believe** that I won’t be shot by some man hiding in a bush in front of me but because I **bet** that I won’t be shot. After all, from a pragmatic standpoint, isn’t this all that matters?

Note that this is an all or nothing bet. It is not that I’d be 5%, 60%, or 95% sure I won’t be shot. I can simply refuse to assign a probability by considering the very concept of it meaningless and simply bet that I won’t get shot.

Does this equate to belief? I understand that in philosophy, there is a definition of belief being a disposition to act, but that is merely an opinion. One can consider beliefs to only be epistemic judgments that one consciously contemplates about a certain matter, and refuse to have any belief on any matter that isn’t logically possible/impossible.

Would this be rational?

Comment: It might be, but it might not be *necessarily* rational. Or, it might be rational for some people some of the time, but not all people all of the time. We perhaps are minded to be cautious in declaring absolutes, here (and elsewhere): there are trivial absolutes like, "Everything is everything," but nontrivial ones are harder (if not impossible, on pain of final contradiction) to confirm.

Comment: What odds are you willing to accept that you won't be shot in the next, say, ten years? I also don't think you'll get shot, but if it's a million to one, I'd be happy to put a dollar on it.

Comment: Regardless of what my answer for that is, why does that imply belief? We don’t live in a world where we actually have to make that bet and put in odds. Each day, we make only one kind of bet/decision in this context: to go outside or to not. That is the only kind of bet. Coming up with actual odds, money, or attaching a figure to it seems useless

Comment: In some multi-valued logics such as Kleene's 3-valued one, there may not be necessary true/false tautological statements, then under such logic you may have to suspend beliefs about *all* statements there possibly are, a complete *epoche* and thus attains ataraxia. Certainly a rational and consistent stance even in face of many staunch Bayesianists ridicules of losing any (metaphoric) bet since under this POV even the moral judgement of losing a bet should be suspended...